# Unlocking GETH RPC to the world

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I have been trying to connect remotely to my node (I have created it purely for Querying the etherium network NO OPEN ACCOUNTS).

I am starting geth like so:
`sudo geth --http --ws -syncmode light --http.corsdomain '*' --http.api eth,web3,debug --ws.origins '*' --ws.api eth,web3,debug --port 30310 --http.addr "0.0.0.0" --ws.addr "0.0.0.0"`

I then test with :
 `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":67}' http://localhost:8545`

Works Fine I get a return.

I then do
 `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":67}' http://77.97.60.10:8545`

No Response .....

ports are open:

```
chris@Laptop-Server:~$ sudo ufw status
[sudo] password for chris: 
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8545                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8546                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
30310                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8545 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8546 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
30310 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Is 77.97.60.10 your external IP or the IP of the host running geth on your local network?

If you're trying to access geth from outside the local network you will also need to open some ports on your firewall/router so you can reach it from outside the local network.

If you are trying to query from another host in your local network make sure you have the IP of the host running geth correct.